# Setting Actionscript Object Keys

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

If I have an array, I can set the keys by doing the following:

```
var example:Array = new Array();

example[20] = "500,45";
example[324] = "432,23";
```

If I want to do something with Objects, how would I achieve this?

I tried the following:

```
var example:Object = [{x:500, y:45}, {x:432, y:23}]; // Works but keys are 0 and 1

var example:Object = [20: {x:500, y:45}, 324: {x:432, y:23}]; // Compile errors

var example:Object = [20]: {x:500, y:45}, [324]: {x:432, y:23}; // Compile errors

var example:Object = [20] {x:500, y:45}, [324] {x:432, y:23}; // Compile errors
```

Is there a good way to achieve this?

I understand I could do this:

```
var example:Object = {id20 : {x:500, y:45}, id324: {x:432, y:23} };
```

But it doesn't suit me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` notation has the same meaning of doing a `new Array()` so when you are doing:

`var example:Object = [{x:500, y:45}, {x:432, y:23}];`

you are in fact creating an array with two elements who are object `{x:500, y:45}` and  `{x:432, y:23}`.

If you want to create an object with key  20 and 324 use the `{}` notation who is the same a `new Object()`

So your example became =>

`var example:Object = {20: {x:500, y:45}, 324: {x:432, y:23}};`

You can do the same as your first example using an `Object` instead of an `Array`:

```
var example:Object = new Object();

example[20] = "500,45";
example[324] = "432,23";
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome. I wish that there was a shorthand notation for this though, but it's great feedback and it works so I'm not complaining! Thanks!