# string to instance name in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm having some problems with as3

```
var eventChildren:XMLList = eventInput.channel.children();
var nr:Number;
nr=0;
for each (var eventInfo:XML in eventChildren) {

    nr++;
    trace(eventInfo.title);
    var ev="ev"+String(nr);
    var titl="title"+String(nr);
    trace(ev);
    trace(titl);

    var newEV:Object = Object(ev);
    var newTITL:Object = Object(titl);

    trace(newEV);
    trace(newTITL);

    newEV.newTITL.text=eventInfo.title;

}

}
```

this is my code, i'm trying to set the title value for every child instance of eventChild, 
as i am new to action script in general, and action script 3 in particular i don't really know what i'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to set the text for ev1.title1, ev2.title2, etc. from values in eventChildren like this : first child, sets ev1.title1, second ev2.title2 and so on. Any ideas on what i should change in the code or where to look for some information ?

edit : thank you for the help, both answers took me to the right solution :

```
for each (var eventInfo:XML in eventChildren) {

    nr++;

    trace(eventInfo.title);
    var ev="ev"+String(nr);
    var titl="title"+String(nr);
    //trace(ev);
    //trace(titl);

    var oTitle:Object = {}; // create object for the field titleXX
    oTitle[titl] = {text:eventInfo.title}; // create and assign the field text to a new object
    allFields[ev] = oTitle; // assign the title object to the field evXX

 }

ev1.title1.text=allFields.ev1.title1.text;
ev2.title2.text=allFields.ev2.title2.text;
ev3.title3.text = allFields.ev3.title3.text;
ev4.title4.text=allFields.ev4.title4.text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ev and titl are `Strings` and not [`Object`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Object.html), **there is no eval in as3 so you will not be able to create a new variable based on a string name** .But you can create a new [`Object`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Object.html) that will have a field based on your `ev` string:

```
var o:Object={};
o[ev]="....";
```

So if ev is equal to the string "ev1" you will have an object with a field named ev1 => o.ev1=...

For the title you can do the same create a new Object that will have a field based on titl string:

```
var o:Object={};
o[titl]="...";
```

So if titl is equal to the string "title1" you will have an object with a field named title1 => o.title1=...

Same thing for the text you have to create an Object to hold the text field.

Mixing all this infos you end up with:

```
var eventChildren:XMLList = eventInput.channel.children();
var nr:Number=0;
var AllFields:Object={};

for each (var eventInfo:XML in eventChildren) {
    nr++;
    trace(eventInfo.title);
    var ev="ev"+String(nr);
    var titl="title"+String(nr);
    trace(ev);
    trace(titl);

    var oTitle:Object = {}; // create object for the field titleXX
    oTitle[titl] = {text:eventInfo.title}; // create and assign the field text to a new object
    allFields[ev] = oTitle; // assign the title object to the field evXX
 }

// then you can have access to all your field within the object allFields
trace(allFields.ev1.title1.text)
trace(allFields.ev2.title2.text)
```

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071871/setting-actionscript-object-keys/2071921#2071921) for object notation

Answer (score 2):

You can create the variable name using 'this':

```
this['mystring'] = new Object();
this.mystring.title = 'mytitle';
```

If you're doing this inside a class, the class has to be dynamic to allow for new members:

```
dynamic public class MyClass extends MovieClip {
    public function MyClass() {
        this['mystring'] = new Object();
        this.mystring.title = 'mytitle';
    }
}
```

If your class is not dynamic, you can still do this but must continue to use array notation rather than dot notation:

```
public class MyClass extends MovieClip { // not dynamic
    public function MyClass() {
        this['mystring'] = new Object();
        this['mystring'].title = 'mytitle';
    }
}
```